# ASP.NET MVC Custom Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is to create an error handling within the application that handles all managed errors, not just MVC related. So I'm not using the HandleErrorAttribute pattern because it is only for MVC errors, not other managed errors.

In my Global.asax I have:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    string displayError = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisplayError"];
    NameValueCollection serverVariables;
    int loop1, loop2;
    StringBuilder serverVariableKeys = new StringBuilder();
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
            // loop through and get server vars
    }

    if (exception != null)
        // Log Error

    // Redirect to Error page if set to basic mode
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayError) && displayError.ToLower() == "basic")
    {
        Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError(); // needed for redirect to work

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
    Response.StatusCode = 500;

    if (httpException != null)
    {
       Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
       switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
        case 403:
          routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
          break;
            case 404:
           routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
           break;
        }
    }

    IController errorsController = new Controllers.ErrorController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
}
```

I have an `ErrorController` that has `General`, `Http403` and `Http404` Actions. I have views that correspond to each action.

In my web.config I have:

```xml
  <system.web>  
    <!-- removed bits to reduce space -->
    <customErrors mode="On" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules >
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <remove name="Session"/>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
```

This works for many scenarios related to managed code, but when IIS takes over, such as bad static file call (example.com/BadFileName.gif) it will return an error from IIS that discloses server details such as local file path. This is because of the following line in the web.config:

```xml
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

But when I set errorMode to other values such as Custom, or just remove the line, my custom error handling stops functioning and the default IIS errors messages are returned for everything including managed code errors.

I've tried a number of things to get to the Custom Errors to work without this setting without any luck, including:

- Setting `CustomError` to `mode="Off"`
- Defining Error nodes under `customError` to redirect to my controllers
- Defining Error nodes under `httpErrors` to redirect to my controllers

When I step through in debugging I can see the call to the controller, but in the end IIS sends the response instead. The error logging does get called correctly Application_Error, so the code does let application handle it to certain point.

Application Details:

- ASP.NET MVC 4.0
- Hosted on IIS 7.5 (Azure Web Site Preview)

Is there way not use `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` and make this work?

Comment: *handles all managed errors* What if the exception is raised by Razer (it's configuration is wrong, assembly is missing etc). What do you expect to render your error page?

Comment: If there is an error in Razor then default to an IIS error. It is a valid point since you could have a runtime error, but I've kept my error pages simple, about 3 lines of Razor code.

Comment: On a side note, have you considered [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)? ([related blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx))

Comment: @Jeroen I did, but I have my own logging code and wanted to capture more detail.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the behaviour is probably that your `Application_Error` handler is correctly being invoked (and invoking your controller), but then IIS is intercepting the 500 error and displaying its own error page. (though it's also possible that your `Application_Error` handler is itself throwing an `Exception`, that's something you'll want to rule out)

Because you want to handle all errors (e.g. the static file error you mentioned), you will likely be unable to rely on either ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC to do the initial error detection for you. **Not all errors come from your application!**

The best thing to do is to lean on IIS 7.5's error handling as much as you can, rather than try to get involved yourself too early. Let IIS do the initial error detection for you and it's much easier.

Try putting the following in your `web.config`, replacing your existing `httpErrors` node:-

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Forbidden" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
</httpErrors>
```

Remove the `customErrors` node entirely. It is unnecessary.

Remember and make sure your error controller is setting the correct status code:-

```
public ActionResult Forbidden()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 403;
    return this.View();
}
```

You should then be able to ditch everything apart from the logging out of your `Application_Error` handler - though I think you'd be best creating your own `HttpModule`; setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` on the modules node in your `web.config` helps you catch errors that would otherwise slip through.

I've got this setup (though I'm personally using elmah to do the logging) running on the Azure Web Sites preview, and it's catching everything except from obviously any errors that come from failing to parse `web.config`.

I've put a [full working example of using httpErrors for custom error pages up on github](https://github.com/iaingalloway/ASP.NET-HttpErrors-Example). You can also [see it live on azure web sites](http://httperrors-example.azurewebsites.net/Home).

Comment: The key seems to be the existingResponse="Replace" attribute that I was missing. Great suggestions, the only thing I'd push back on is the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" suggestion. I've read that setting hurts performance and creates a few bugs. The suggestion instead is to set preCondition="" -- downside is you have to reference each module.

Comment: existingResponse="Replace" saved the day!

Comment: `existingResponse="Replace"` will force IIS to replace the error response even if `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` is set to `true`. It is common to use `TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true` when returning JSON from an AJAX request... otherwise, IIS will replace JSON response with a response of it's own. Reference: [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18774885/195417)

Comment: Interesting, but that seems to be by design. The OP wants to show the error page "for all error pages, not just MVC related". You're unlikely to want custom errors on a Web API, and in any case an AJAX client still has the error code to indicate that something has gone wrong.

Comment: Question--when you use IIS to intercept the error, is there any place to log the error?  I find that when I use this approach my asp.net Application_Error method is never invoked, and in my error controller "Server.GetLastError" is null.

Comment: Note for future users: Do not have a tilde in your path when using http errors. It won't work. E.g. /Error/NotFound will look in error controller and action relative to your web.config file. ~/Error/NotFound will not work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, one question, I want to log the exception, I have my logging code setup in Application_Error but this now does not execute. How do I go about logging the exception with the above method? Thanks

Comment: @IainGalloway Thank you; two notes: 1) GitHub solution works as-is in Visual Studio 2017 and IIS Express 10.x, but when deployed to IIS 7.5 in a site subfolder which I had converted to an app, I had to change path="/Error/Forbidden" to path="/MyAppFolder/Error/Forbidden"...otherwise I got empty/blank screen content with 403 forbidden or 404 not found errors, depending on environment (makes sense, in retrospect); and 2) URL /Errors/Other/400 (note plural "Errors") throws default 500 response, not 400, because the catchall route passes "id" and not "code" to controller action Other(), ... (cont)

Comment: (cont, from above) ... so param code is null. I fixed by changing URL param for MapRoute name=Errors, to "Error/{action}/{id}", and controller action Other param to "id"...now both /Error/Other/400 and /Errors/Other/400 throw 400...just a quibble/nitpick in an otherwise very simple solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this in your app you can write a custom handler or use the HandleError Attribute [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-handling-exceptions-and-404.html) is a good example of one way to approach this instead of having to use IIS as a crutch. as not all IIS host providers will allow this type of customization at the server level and IMO is a bad way to approach since it creates extra configuration at deployment time.