# Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis

I have a page where i want the page to return a 404 response but remain on that page. Please don't ask why - the client wants it that way even after i discussed it with him.

I've got a .net page written in C# running under iis 8 and the app pool is configured to run under 4.0 integrated mode

When i set the statuscode to 404 in the page, it gets sent to the custom 404 error page that's set up for this site. After googling i found another post on SO mention using Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors. From what i read it sounds like it's exactly what i need. I tried setting it to true and it had no effect in the behavior of the page - still get sent to the customer 404 error page that's setup in iis.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: One reason for doing this is SEO purposes -- letting Google (etc.) know that that URL is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, I mean if you actually had a discussion with your client about this, I really don't think you did a good enough job arguing your side. From a simple business perspective, this is disastrous. Google and all the other search engines are going to ding the hell out of the site for this, and if you're not getting good placement in search engines, you basically don't exist. As a business owner, you might as well close up shop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well - this is a first. First time I managed to find the answer before hitting the submit button :)

Found this IIS.net article:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors
which then lead me to find this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690576(v=vs.90).aspx

Scroll down to the part that explains what the options for `existingResponse` mean. I had mine set to `Replace` which means it ignores `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` completely. Changed it to `Auto` and it's working.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, your link pointed me to the right solution: `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`

Comment: Another option in code is Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors AND Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect.  I find that all other error codes will work accept a 401 which IIS likes to redirect as a 200 to the login page when Forms Authentication is being used.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Auto doesnt serve custom error pages configured in httperrors . how you have made it work  ?